# Business Data Connectivity choice does not appear in Type dropdown on the Create New Connection page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, bdc, ups

This is in SharePoint 2016 Enterprise, I am logged into Central Admin with the farm admin account.

Trying to get a Business Data Connectivity working. I've created an application in the Secure Store, created an External Content Type in SP designer, and now want to hook it all together.

I went to *Central Administration > Application Management > Manage service applications > User Profile Service (Synch) > Configure Synchronization Connections*.

On that page I clicked on *Create New Connection*, but on the popup page I do not see a choice in the Type drop-down for a BDC. Does someone know why? Does something need to be configured to have a BDC available here?

[image]

Comment: Hi @user66953, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)